# Laravel 5: when logged in entering URL, Laravel redirects to /home

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, routes, laravel-5

I am building login functionality (rather say using it) and when I enter manualy 
`Route::get('/offers', 'OfferController@index')`,  I get redirected to `/home`.

Before login functionality my route was working just normal.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Are you requesting /offers as an authenticated user or guest? Do you have any middleware applied on that route? Do you have a route /home that you defined?

Comment: Are you using any of AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, AuthenticatesUsers, RedirectsUsers, RegistersUsers or ResetsPasswords in your OfferController?

Comment: There is a $this->middleware('guest'); in my Offer constructor. Is this causing this behaviour?

Comment: Yes. I'm posting an answer with an explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting the redirect is because you are using **guest** middleware on **/offers** route.

The purpose of the **guest** middleware (which uses **RedirectIfAuthenticated** class) is to redirect authenticated users out from pages that should be accessible only for guests, e.g. login form or registration page. Hence the middleware name **guest**. The middleware checks if user is authenticated and redirects authenticated users to **/home** which is exactly what you are experiencing.

You can see the code of the middleware here: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/Http/Middleware/RedirectIfAuthenticated.php. The whole logic happens in its **handle()** method.

Comment: Thank you, I will dive into it.